# trouble with SQL Join statement and Referencing the items in my sql statement

Tags: php, sql, join, left-join

First thing is I think there are errors in my SQL Join statement (syntax or other). I am using 2 tables in the statement, one called artists, the other is called prints. Next, further down in my php script I reference the items in my sql statement with a MYSQLI_ASSOC fetch array. I think there are problems in there too.

here is the sql statement:

```
    $sql = "SELECT CONCAT(a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.last_name) AS name p.print_name, p.price, p.size, p.description, p.what_genre, p.quantity_on_hand FROM artists AS a LEFT JOIN prints AS p USING (artist_id) ORDER BY $order_by $limit";
```

here is the second part:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $bg = ($bg=='#eeeeee' ? '#ffffff' : '#eeeeee');
            $list .= '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">';
            $list .= '<td>' . $row['name'] . '</td><td>' . $row['print_name'] . '</td><td>' . $row['price'] . '</td><td>' . $row['size'] . '</td><td>' . $row['description'] . '</td><td>' . $row['what_genre'] . '</td><td>' . $row['quantity_on_hand'] . '</td></tr>';
        }
```

Here are some error messages I got:

Notice:
    Query:SELECT CONCAT(a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.last_name) AS name p.print_name, p.price, p.size, p.description, p.what_genre, p.quantity_on_hand FROM artists AS a LEFT JOIN prints AS p USING (artist_id) ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 0,5You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'p.print_name, p.price, p.size, p.description, p.what_genre, p.quantity_on_hand F' at line 1

```
in D:\xampp\htdocs\larry\chapter192\view_users2.php on line 68

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\larry\chapter192\view_users2.php on line 110
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma between `AS name` and `p.print_name`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.last_name) AS name, p.print_name
```